# Sourcing multiple R files in

Tags: java, r, function, google-cloud-dataflow, renjin

Currently I am using R on my local machine, where I am able to source multiple R scripts conditionally (as they are placed in my local drive).

However when I need to use same scripts on RENJIN in Google Data Flow to achieve parallelism , I am unable to source files.

I have multiple R script files with .R extension. I need to read the main R script file and need to pass into data flow at run time but the main R file has to source tag that is referencing to other R script files. 
When reading the main R file content from java and passing it to google data flow Jave is not able to interpret source tags within R files which is referencing to other R script files .

To handle this situation I may use one untidy solution to keep entire code in one file. with different function names.

Is there any way in Renjin to hold all the R script files which needs to be used and pass to google data flow at run time.

Answer (score 0):

The most logical solution would be to use a package here. I assume that you can install custom packages on the google cloud (just having base R would be painful). I would then put these functions and code inside an R package, and install that package. This would get rid of the use of `source` and enable the inclusion of documentation and testing.

Comment: Thanks, Paul... yes this can be one of the way.i was thinking if we can use these files as it is using source or any other syntax.... making package can be lil difficult for me as I have never tried

Answer (score 0):

If your sources are included as resources in a JAR you are deploying to Google Cloud Dataflow, then you can source them using a 'res' URL:

```
source("res:com/acme/scripts/myscript.R")
```

If you can't change the paths in the script, then make sure they are at least relative, for example:

```
source("myscript.R")
```

And then set the working directory when you create a new ScriptEngine.

```
RenjinScriptEngineFactory factory = new RenjinScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngine();
engine.eval("setwd('res:com/acme/scripts')");
```

Note that setting the working directory to somewhere on the classpath only works reliably if there is only one JAR on the classpath with that path. If, for example, I evaluate:

```
> setwd("res:org/renjin")
> getwd()
[1] "jar:file:///usr/share/renjin/lib/compiler-0.8.2337.jar!/org/renjin"
```

The above sets the working directory to the first directory 'org/renjin' on the classpath, which is might not be what you want.

In any case, I would definitely encourage you to put the files together in package as suggested above, but maybe this will help get things moving.

Comment: Hi akbertram, I created a java project with package com.acme.scripts and pasted all my R files in the package and created a jar file of that. Then I included that jar file in my project where I need these R files to execute in script engine need to feed it in google dataflow. These are the result of this approach.

Comment: Not working
engine.eval("setwd('res:com/acme/scripts')");
System.out.println("Working directory - "+engine.eval("getwd()"));
org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Badly formed URI "res:com/acme/scripts".

Working 
engine.eval("setwd('res:org/renjin')");
System.out.println("Working directory - "+engine.eval("getwd()"));
Working directory - jar:file:///C:/Users/anurag/.m2/repository/org/renjin/renjin-script-engine/0.8.2298/renjin-script-engine-0.8.2298.jar!/org/renjin

Comment: Double check the JAR file you're including. You should be able to open it from Windows explorer and verify that there is a directory "com" containing a directory "acme" containing a directory "scripts" containing your R files.